# Node npm global install of express cloud9

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am trying to install express globally in cloud 9 IDE. I run the following command -

npm install -g express

then on the bash prompt I enter -

express --version

I get unknown command error?

Can I not install stuff globally on cloud 9 ?

Niladri

Comment: solved? same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add environment variables to achieve that in windows some times.  May be you can try that there.